# Is centripetal force directly proportional or inversely proportional to the radius?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

There are two formulas that represent centripetal force, $F_c=mv^2/r$ and $F_c=m\omega^2r=4\pi^2f^2mr$. 
Which one is correct under which circumstances?

Comment: It depends on what is kept constant.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. They are equivalent.

In constant circular motion velocity $v$, radius $r$ and frequency $f$ are related by
$$v = 2\pi r f.$$

And therefore is
$$\frac{mv^2}{r}=4\pi^2 rmf^2.$$